# Duplicating Objective C files?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm working on my project in Xcode writing in Objective C & I like to know, is there a way to duplicate files? I keep looking it up on the internet  & in my books, I can't fond anything. Whenever I try to #include, it doesn't seem to work.

This is what I have so far, this is the .h file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController :UIViewController {
}
- (IBAction)link;
@end

#include <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController2 :UIViewController {
}
- (IBAction)link;
@end

This is the /m file which doesn't want to work.

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
-(IBAction)link {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
     openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://twitter.com/sexybeast914"]];
}

@end

#include "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
-(IBAction)link {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
     openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://twitter.com/sexybeast914"]];
}

@end
```

I always get the same to errors, "Cannot declare class extension for "ViewController", & "Reimplementation of class "ViewController"

If someone could help, it would be nice.

Thanks, :)

Comment: You renamed the 2nd class to `ViewController2` in the .h but you forgot to rename the 2nd class extension and 2nd class implementation to `ViewController2`.

Comment: Why in the world would you want to have two identical classes???  If you need two instances just create two instances of a single class.  (And if you need two minor variations of a single class learn about class inheritance.)

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring the class `ViewController` twice.  You can't have two classes of the same name.

I'm betting that second copy of `ViewController` was meant to be `ViewController2` and you forgot to rename it in the file after copy/pasting the code from the first file?

Comment: Actually the two classes are declared differently (`ViewController` and `ViewController2`). The problem is the two corresponding class extensions and the implementations are both for `ViewController`. The second class extension needs to be changed to `ViewController2 ()` and the second implementation needs to be `ViewController2`.

Comment: So is there a way to duplicate Objective-C files?

Comment: @bbum But he is copying the class so I would guess the 2nd class extension (as well as the implementation) should be renamed.

Comment: Yeah -- most likely.  It really does look like a copypasta error.